# Claire Voisin's books?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request

Are there free legal equivalent books (or freely available lecture notes or courses) of Claire Voisin: Hodge theory and complex algebraic geometry 1 and 2?

Comment: It's certainly not legal and someone with higher morals than I will surely yell at you about it. To the OP: if you are also principled then I would look for lecture notes in Hodge theory. Off the top of my head I know Christian Schnell and Matt Kerr have good stuff like this. They don't cover as much, though. There is also this newer book by Cattani et al that is available freely from one of the authors http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~fouad.elzein/Hodge.pdf which covers quite a lot. To be honest I still haven't made it deep into Vol II of Voisin so the topics might diverge.

Comment: Thank you for your help..I got the Cattani et al's book..Thank you so much..

Answer (score 2):

You can check out the lecture notes referenced in this MO question - [Hodge Theory (Voisin)](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/141555):

[INTRODUCTION TO HODGE THEORY](http://www.imar.ro/~dmatei/snsb/hodge.pdf) (by Daniel Matei)

There is also the following lecture notes by Claire Voisin herself:

[Hodge theory and the topology of compact Kähler and complex projective manifolds](http://www.math.columbia.edu/~thaddeus/seattle/voisin.pdf)

Comment: You're welcome!  =)