# Are there any useful and comprehensive lectures or videos related to that of the topic of Hodge theory?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, hodge-theory

I am planning to use Claire Voisin's books for learning Hodge theory. They have a look towards algebraic geometry, which is one of my main areas of study. Notes and papers are ok too.

Comment: There is a [similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1451302/claire-voisins-books) to this, if not a duplicate. See if it helps you.